# How get the correct form of code html with (Input...) angular2

Tags: html, typescript, angular

I need to get all the code with input as [input] and tag as #tag

because when I try to get code html with jquery         `console.log($("#content")[0].outerHTML);`

for exemple this part of code become

```
 <div dnd-droppable [dropZones]="['docGrid']" (onDropSuccess)="transferDataSuccess()" class="page" id="content" size="A5" layout="portrait" >
                    <div #content  hidden></div>
                </div>
```

like this

```
<div _ngcontent-ugk-10="" class="page" dnd-droppable="" id="content" layout="portrait" size="A5" ng-reflect-dropzones="docGrid">
                    <div _ngcontent-ugk-10="" hidden=""></div>
                </div>
```

I need to get come like is wrote in my IDE thanks

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: I need just to get the same code that I wrote in my IDE . when I want to get the code html there is some difference as is shown in the example thanks

Comment: This is normal, as Angular takes over your html

Comment: Perhaps you could explain **why** you need jquery to get the exact code as you typed it, then we would be able to help you figure out a way to solve your problem.

Comment: I need to save my code html in database in server side 
for to get it in the server and add it in my html and can apply on it
(because dropZone for example after change is not working)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of doing that, you can however get the inline template of the `Component`. But you cannot alter it. To get the inline template (and when there is only 1 annotation on your Component) you can use:

```
Reflect.getMetadata('annotations', ComponentClass)[0].template;
```

For instance if you have an `AppComponent`:

```
@Component({
   selector : 'app',
   template : '<div>hi</div>'
})
export class AppComponent {

   constructor() {
      console.log(Reflect.getMetadata('annotations', AppComponent)[0].template;) 
      //<div>hi</div>
   }

}
```

Comment: where and how to use this reflect.getMetadata ? there is some import to add? thanks

Comment: I added an example. No import necessary. It comes from the reflect-metadata node_module

Comment: I added it but I have an error Property 'getMetadata' does not exist on type 'typeof Reflec

I added this as import import 'reflect-metadata';
I'm using angular2 rc2
I think getMetadata have 3 parametrs

Comment: You should not use an import, because then it doesn't work. Check [here](https://github.com/rbuckton/ReflectDecorators/blob/master/reflect-metadata.d.ts). You can see the `getMetadata` function. There are multiple, but you only need the first one with 2 arguments

Comment: I rremoved the import and it still get te same error :(

        console.log(Reflect.getMetadata('annotations',SectionsTemplateComponent)[0].template);

it Called in constructor

Comment: Have you added `"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3"` to your `package.json`?